# Parse JSON C# Error

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm try to getting JSON data but getting Error.

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line
>   0, position 0.

I'm using Net 4.5 and JSON.Net Framework
Here my code

```
WebClient net = new WebClient();
string str = await net.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
JObject o = JObject.Parse(str); // ERROR Here
```

And my code JSON Data View on Webservice
http://sv1.volcanosoft.com/test/index.php?area=ho-chi-minh
this site format index.php UTF-8 and header of php file

```
header('Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo '{"item":';
echo json_encode($data);
echo '}';
```

Comment: I don't think `str`'s content is as you have posted. My guess you get an error or redirect page with Html content.

Comment: Is this the JSON data in str when you debug it or before downloading the string?

Comment: Your posted JSON string seems valid as http://jsonlint.com says

Comment: ok. I posted JSON Data when Debug

Comment: sorry about this. I'm edited

Comment: Could you just try this without downloading the string: JObject o = JObject.Parse("...the JSON data like posted here...");

Comment: same here, JSON data seems ok. I've just tested it with http://jsonlint.com/. But look at error message: `when parsing value: .` Notice that the value quoted in the error is empty, maybe that's the point?

Comment: just as boindiil has pointed out that this is valid JSON

Comment: i'm edit new data and format of webservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The downloaded string starts with two [byte order marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (U+FEFF), which JSON.NET parser (correctly) doesn't understand.

The reason why the downloaded string contains two BOMs is because the data your service is sending contains 3 of them. The first one is removed automatically by UTF-8 encoding, but the two other remain.

BOM can be useful with files, where you can't store the charset used. But you are sending the charset used in a header, so you don't need to send BOM at all. And sending three of them is certainly incorrect.

I believe this is caused by BOMs in your PHP files, so you should probably remove them from there.

Comment: thank you. It done :D  . But how to convert
`Tiêu đề &#193;o kho&#225;c nữ m&#224;u da b&#242;`
to Unicode ?